# Get Smarty template (with data passed) as string

Tags: php, smarty

I'm working with a legacy code that uses Smarty. For one of the Ajax requests I need to return HTML code of a sub-template. Hence, **I would like to pass a variable to the sub-template and store the processed template as string**, so it can be passed back to Ajax callback.

I have no idea how to do that. Smarty `fetch()` seems to do something like that, but I'm unable to pass `$myData` into the sub-template.

What I want is this:

```
$content = $smarty->get_template_as_string('results.tpl', $myData);
return $content;
```

The `get_template_as_string()` method does not exist in Smarty, just serves as an example of what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Smarty doesn't take its data as an array, you need to assign each variable individually; luckily, all you need to do this is a simple `foreach` loop:

```
    foreach ($variables as $key => $value) {
        $this->assign($key, $value);
    }
```

Then, as you say, `fetch` will render the actual template for you:

```
    $html = $this->fetch($template_file_name);
```

Obviously you can wrap all of this up in whatever kind of utility function makes sense for you.

Comment: Thank you! Assigning the data before calling `fetch()` did the trick. And btw, Smarty doesn't seem to have problems with assigning an array, so no loop needed ;)